# WYSIWYG image not working on tab content page detail

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-1.9, rwd

I am having problem with the WYSIWYG editor. When I try to put image, and save it and check the site, its not working although the image is there on the editor.

Try to firebug it, this what I've found

```
<img alt="WD My Cloud" wdsfmycloud.jpg"}}"="" product_images="" wysiwyg="" src="{{media url=" title="WD My Cloud" style="float: right;">
```

[image]

How can I fix it?

Please help

Comment: have you clear the cache?

Comment: cache is disabled

Comment: Click on button "Show/Hide Editor" and paste the piece of code of image, please.

Comment: this is the code

<img style="float: right;" title="WD My Cloud" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/product_images/wdsfMyCloud.jpg"}}" alt="WD My Cloud" />